# Equivalente de stata en R, bucles, for,

Tags: r, bucle-for, variables, bucles, stata

quisiera saber si en R existe algo equivalente a los bucles de  STATA

```
x1
x2
x3

foreach i of numlist 1:3 {
    total x`i'
}
```

pero en R no encuentro como representar las comillas espaciales.
`i'

Answer (score 2):

En R no es necesario usar esas comillas especiales, al punto que no existen en R.

Te muestro un ejemplo.

Si tienes el siguiente data frame.

```
df<-data.frame(x1=1:5,x2=3:7,x3=10:14)
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  3 10
2  2  4 11
3  3  5 12
4  4  6 13
5  5  7 14
```

Y quieres sumarle a cada columna el valor de 10 podrías hacerlo con un for, en stata sería así.

```
foreach v of varlist x1 x2 x3 {
replace `v' = `v' +10
}
```

Pero en R, sería más sencillo.

```
# Una posible forma.
for (i in c("x1","x2","x3")){
  df[,i]<-df[,i]+10
}

# Una segunda posible forma. 
for (i in 1:3) {
  df[,i]<-df[,i]+10
}

# Una tercera posible forma. Usando un for implícito.
apply(df[,1:3],2, function(x) x+10)
```

En la primera se hace llamando por el nombre al vector, en el segundo usando índices (la posición de la columna) y en la tercera usando un `for` implícito.

En ninguna el iterador usó comillas, ya que el iterador llama al objeto como lo has definido previamente, en el primer caso como caracter (nombre de la variable) y en el segundo como número (posición de la columna).

Hay más posibilidades de hacer el mismo ejercicio, pero estás serían solo algunas.